# Redirect 301 Not Working after modifiction

Tags: redirect

I would like to add redirection:

```
http://www.example.com/hebradio/index.php?radio=11 ---> http://example.com/radio/reshet-gimel
```

to my (wordpress) site, to the current htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^radio=11$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/radio/reshet-gimel [L,R=301]
```

As you can see I add it to the end of file... but, it doen't work :(
What can I do about? Thanks!

Comment: You need to escape . characters in regular expressions. So /index.php$ should be /index\.php

Comment: My rewrites also have RewriteEngine on just about the first RewriteCond too.